# How to separate content from my query into 3 distinct columns

Tags: sql-server

I have got the following query, which puts the data that I need (text in the 245, 260 and 300 tags of my table called "bib") into a single column (called "Title"). Instead I would like to have this data separated into three distinct columns, one for each tag. Any suggestions would be very welcome

```
SELECT DISTINCT isbnEX_inverted.isbn, ISNULL(bib.text, CONVERT(varchar(255), bib_longtext.longtext)) AS Title, top_circ_summary.ranking, bib.tag, bib.bib#
FROM         bib INNER JOIN
                      item ON bib.bib# = item.bib# INNER JOIN
                      isbnEX_inverted ON bib.bib# = isbnEX_inverted.bib# INNER JOIN
                      top_circ_summary ON item.bib# = top_circ_summary.bib# LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      bib_longtext ON bib.bib# = bib_longtext.bib# AND bib.tag = bib_longtext.tag
WHERE     (isbnEX_inverted.isbn LIKE '%978__________%') AND (top_circ_summary.collection_group = 'jfic') AND (bib.tag in ('245', '520', '300'))
order by top_circ_summary.ranking
```

Here's a sample of the (tab separated) output

```
isbn    Title   ranking tag bib# 9780143307334  a217 p. :bill. ;c21
cm. 1   300 962366 9780143307334    aDiary of a wimpy kid :bthe third
wheel /cby Jeff Kinney. 1   245 962366 9780143307334    aTrying to find
a partner for the Valentine's Day dance, Greg finds solace in the fact
that his best friend Rowley also doesn't have a date, but an
unexpected twist might turn his night around.   1   520 962366
```

Comment: Can you retry the formatting of the output?  The lines have wrapped.  You want to put four spaces at the beginning of each line or highlight the area and click on `{}` for the formatting.

Comment: Hi Folks,Sorry, I should have described my issue a bit better originally. What's currently happening is that the data for each of the three tags (245,260 and 300) is inserted into distinct rows in the output. Instead I would like to display this data in a single row, but separate columns for each tag.